# Element in linear subspace with maximum number of zeros

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-algebra

Given a real matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ I would like to find an element $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $v - Mx$ has maximum number of zeros.

If the matrix $M$ has rank $n$ then it is easy to find some $x$ where $xM = v$. But in the case where $m<n$ the best I can think right now is to check all $m \times m$ submatrices of $M$, solve the system of equations and see the resulting 0s we get. Maximize over the number to find an ideal vector. This has complexity $O\left(\binom{n}{m} m^{3}\right)$.

I wonder if it's possible to do better. Say in the $m=\sqrt{n}$ regime with $n$ large.

We can define this weird "metric", where for some $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ say  $\| v \|_{\#0} = n - \text{# of zeros in } v$. Then essentially we are looking for the best $\| - \|_{\#0}$ projection of $v$ in the subspace spanned by the columns of $M$. There are very efficient methods for different metrics, like least squares method for $\| - \|_2$. But those metrics behave better with linear algebraic techniques. Obviously another annoying part of the question is that the solution is not necessarily unique.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  A nitpick: You can't represent elements of $\mathbb{R}$ on a computer.  Do you mean $\mathbb{Q}$?  $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Oh haha yes you're right. I guess you can do floating point and then some tolerance. But it's easier to do rationals, the question is the same.

Comment: 1. I suspect there might be more hope for efficient algorithms if you happen to be in a setting where you know there exists a solution where the number of non-zero elements of $v-Mx$ is much less than $n-m$.  2. If $M,v$ are random (and has no structure), then I suspect that with extremely high probability, the optimal answer will have $m$ zeros (and $n-m$ non-zeros), so it'll suffice to sample one or a few submatrices.  So I'm guessing the problem only becomes interesting when $M$ has some structure that allows better solutions.